# To identify different between oracle Java Hotspot JVM and JDK which can be downloaded from Oracle website

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

Is Oracle Hotspot JVM is same as what we can download from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html ? 
If not from where we can downlaod Java Hotspot JVM.

Comment: The JVM is part of the JRE that is shipped with the jdk.

Answer (score 0):

The link is HotSpot JVM
You can download it and check with

```
java-version
```

and will find like

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```